# Sort by year then count dummy variable for each county (ddply)

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

I'm trying to summarize a very large dataframe using ddply.

I need to sort by year, then for each county(fips) count when RVPI == 1.  I'm not sure how to do this within ddply and would appreciate any help.

Here is a sample code :

```
Lines <- "year  fips   RVPI  indivID
1950   1001 1 1
1950   1001 1 2    
1950   1001 1 3     
1951   1001 1 3  
1951   1001 1 4  
1951   1002 0 5  
1952  1002  0 6  
1952  1003  0 6  
1952  1004  1 7  
1952  1004  1 7  
1953  1004 1 8 
1953  1006 0 8
1953  1001 1 8
1953  1006 0 9 "

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, check.names = FALSE, header = TRUE)
df <- as.data.frame(DF)

ddply(df, .(year), summarize,
      RVPI = sum(RVPI))
```

Expected Outcome for table (not exact from example above, but in general)

```
Year     RVPI(# of counties)
1950        1
1951        1
1952        1
1953        2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea using `dplyr`. Here I removed rows which have 0 in RVPI. Then, for each year, I picked up one entry for each `fips` using `distinct`. For example, there are three rows with year 1950 with fips 1001. `distinct` picks up just one of them. Finally, I counted how many fips exist for each year.

```
library(dplyr)

filter(df, RVPI != 0) %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    distinct(fips) %>%
    summarise(numOfFips = n())
```

Alternatively, this produces the same outcome.

```
summarise(group_by(df, year, fips), sumRVPI = sum(RVPI)) %>%
    filter(sumRVPI != 0) %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    summarize(numOfFips = n())

#  year numOfFips
#1 1950         1
#2 1951         1
#3 1952         1
#4 1953         2
```

If you try to include `indivID` in an output, you could do something like this.

```
filter(df, RVPI != 0) %>%
    group_by(year, fips) %>%
    summarise(numOfIndiv = n()) %>%
    summarise(numOfFips = n(), numOfIndiv = sum(numOfIndiv)) 

#  year numOfFips numOfIndiv
#1 1950         1          3
#2 1951         1          2
#3 1952         1          2
#4 1953         2          2
```

Comment: Thanks.  This works, but I don't need a summary including fips.  Since my database is so large it's spitting out every fips in every year, and I need the aggregate of those totals over the years

Comment: Is this what you expected? Let me know.

Comment: I need total counties(fips) that have RVPI == 1, for each year.  So I need Year | RVPI as a table and each RVPI is the number of counties(fips) with the RVPI == 1.  Is this more clear?  Thanks for your help

Comment: Would you mind if I ask you to write your expected outcome (a table) in your question? That will be very helpful. :)

Comment: Sure.  I added a general table I'm looking for.  See above.

Comment: Would you be able to create expected outcome with your sample data? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Changed the expected outcome up top to what the output should be

Comment: Not `ddply` solution. But, I revised my idea above. :)

Comment: This is great and does appear to work, but unfortunately I need it to work in ddply since I'm building a large summary table that includes many other variables.  As an example above, also including the number of indivID in each year.

Comment: I got one more idea including indivID. But, this is an idea for only two variables. Anything going beyond this, I am afraid I won't be able to help you. Sorry, mate. Somebody else will be able to suggest an idea with `ddply`.

Comment: Ok thanks.  This answered my question and got me started.  Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure. Hope you can proceed further from here. good luck. :)

Comment: @jazzurro, in your last option, you wouldn't need the second `group_by` since after the first one, the data is only grouped by `year`. Two more options that produce the same as your first two would be `filter(DF, RVPI == 1) %>% count(year, fips) %>% count(year)` and `filter(DF, RVPI == 1) %>% group_by(year) %>% summarise(n = n_distinct(fips))`.

Comment: @beginneR Hi ya, sorry for this late reply. Being out all day. Thank you very much for the two more options. I like the count option. I was initially confused with the question, and I could not see `count`. Thank for the advice for the last option as well. I will revise that, and then off to bed!